# High CPU usage on a .NET application

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, dump

I am facing a weird issue, our in house built .NET application is running a 50% CPU load and doesn't seem to function right.

The application uses WatiN to invoke several actions that perform web app testing, i am suspecting that some threads or code is left and not cleaned up (disposed) correctly, but not sure.

I have performed the following:

1. Took several dumps (by using Task Manager).
2. Took a peek using Windbg on the running managed threads to see if there's anything obvious.
3. Run the !dlk SOSEX command to see if there's any deadlock going on.
4. Run DebugDiag 1.2 on all captured 3 dumps.

I have uploaded the DebugDiag report here: [DebugDiag Report](http://www.sendspace.com/file/qduuur)

I am not sure if i am missing anything obvious, what can i check here?

Comment: Well, the obivious question is - what are your threads doing when you see that high load? What did you see when you used windbg?

Comment: Just FYI; generally speaking, deadlocks won't cause high cpu, since the threads involved are simply blocked.

Comment: It doesn't seem like its doing a high load operation. One point of interest is the fact that DebugDiag states that GC is running, although some thread that issued the GC cannot be preempted. The message in detail: The following threads in RAF (2).DMP are waiting for .net garbage collection to finish. Thread 15 triggered the garbage collection.The gargage collector thread wont start doing its work till the time the threads which have pre-emptive GC disabled have finished executing. The following threads have pre-emptive GC disabled 14,

Comment: @AndrewBarber i know. Thanks for pointing out. When experiencing weird behaviour, i am checking ALL directions :)

Comment: I believe that the easiest way to get what your application doing is to look into source code. If you don't have source code, you can try decompile it using Reflector. It's pretty difficult to find problem from outside of application if you know pretty small about that application.

Comment: But where in the source code should i look, as all running threads aren't doing high load work, or running some .net framework code, like methods on the threadpool class

Comment: Did you check the threads to see which one is consuming the most CPU time?

Comment: I have tracked down the location in code where this problem is occuring. After digging deep, i found that under some conditions there is a while loop that never exits. Are there any tools that can help in finding this ? for example, some graphic profiler that shows where all the CPU cycles are being spent in? i couldn't find such case that allows hooking into an already running process.

Comment: If indeed the infinite loop is hit, you should be able to observe a pattern in the dumps (which is unlikely as you did not). So if the GC is running and leads to the high CPU usage, you may check how much memory is used in the dumps. The memory usage may provide you more insights.

Comment: The DebugDiag report is apparently not available anymore, so I couldn't take a look at it. If the process is using 50% CPU then at least one thread must be doing a lot of work. Try using the `!runaway` command. It will show you CPU usage per thread. From there you can go to each relevant thread and inspect their call stacks.